# javascript or css: How to Hide any Number followed by dot Prefix "1.text", "2.text"..."30.text" from a Text inside a Label

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide, prefix

I want to hide with javascript or css all (numbers followed by dots) prefixes from a text inside a Label.
hide "1.", "2."..."30." from "1.text", "2.text"..."30.text" from the texts of a Label.

```html
HTML
<li>
<label class="layered_nocolor">
1.alpha
</label>
</li>
<li>
<label class="layered_nocolor">
2.beta
</label>
</li>
<li>
<label class="layered_nocolor">
30.gama
</label>
</li>
```

i want my page to show the texts without the prefixes

```
alpha
beta
gama
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to hide anything by using CSS **OR** Javascript. You will need both of them. You will have to use CSS to hide the label and Javascript to changing dinamically the style of your label. First of all, create a CSS class called hide:

```
.hide{
   display: none;
 }
```

then, in your HTML, you will add this script:

```
// Gets all your HTML element with the class "layered_nocolor".
var labels = document.getElementsByClassName("layered_nocolor");
// The regex pattern you want to hide. It means "one or more digit before a dot".
var pattern = "(/d+\.)";
// Iterates all the elements you got from before. 
for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
  // If your label match the regex pattern you change the class hiding it.
  if(labels[i].innerHTML.match(pattern) != null){
    labels[i].class = "layered_nocolor hide";
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

After your explanation, this is the code you are looking for:

```
// Gets all your HTML element with the class "layered_nocolor".
var labels = document.getElementsByClassName("layered_nocolor");
// The regex pattern you want to hide. It means "one or more digit before a dot".
var pattern = "(/d+\.)";
// Iterates all the elements you got from before. 
for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
  // If your label match the regex pattern you replace the text with "" to remove it.
 (labels[i].innerHTML.replace(pattern, "");
}
```

**EDIT 2**

If you are using jQuery, this is the best way to do it:

```
$(".layered_nocolor").html(function(i, oldhtml){return oldhtml.replace(/\\d+\\./, "");});
```

The double "\" are important because if you insert it only once, it will be used as an escape character instead of a literal.

Comment: thnx for answering!
i don't want to hide the class, only the prefix from the text
i still want the text vissible
i just want to see alpha beta gama without the prefixes

Comment: Then, simply wrap the text you may want to hide into a <span> and give that span a class. The code will be the same, you will only have to change the class "layered_nocolor" with the new class name.

Comment: i cannot edit the html, the text comes from prestashop filters i put prefixes on the names so i can have a custom order in the values and not by name.
and now i want to hide the prefixes so customers cannot see them.

Comment: there should be a way similar to this example:
whan i wanted to hide the whole filter when it contained the text "design"
i used $("#filter_name td:contains('design')").parent("tr").hide();
but now i want to hide only the prefix of the filter inside the text so only the text is visible as i said lets say the filter has the values 1.alpha 2.beta i want to see only alpha beta in the filter values

Comment: sry guys this didn't work maybe because i didn't mention that the text in the html is in quotes "1.alpha" but in the site they are not visible. ididn't mention them cause i thought tha the code u could provide me was just a find the prefix and hide it sry for being unclear.
this is my site it's in greek. http://aurorahome.gr/13-sentonia could u take a look on the actual html of the filter "Διάσταση" and not the crappy example i gave you. so sorry guys

Comment: it just messed with the filters.Surely i didn't implemented well, i'm more familiar with Barmar's addition of javascript in my theme's custom js input

Comment: could u take a look in the actual site filter values of filter "Διασταση" http://aurorahome.gr/13-sentonia

Comment: Where's the filter in your site?

Comment: second to the left column below price range if you go to the category link i gave you

Comment: If you are using jQuery, this worked for me (tested on your website): $(".layered_nocolor").html(function(i, oldhtml){return oldhtml.replace(/\d+\./, "");});

Comment: i inserted it but changed nothing. should i have added anything else beside this code?
when i inserted your code and saved the input page when i returned the code had change to $(".layered_nocolor").html(function(i, oldhtml){return oldhtml.replace(/d+./, "");});

Comment: Where did you put the code? To make it execute on page loading, you can put it inside a script tag like this: $( document ).ready( *function goes here* );

Comment: i put it in my theme's custom js input area http://picpaste.com/pics/Untitled_5.1461969749.png.

i don't think i have to use the $( document ).ready...
everything else i have put there like hiding a filter with a certain name works but as you see when i save the code u gave me and go back to the input area, the regular expression has changed by itself from (/\d+\./, "") to (/d+./, "")

Comment: Try this instead: (/\\d+\\./, "")

Comment: Yeah that did it thank you so much i just have to put the extra slashes everytime i visit the page cause it keeps eating them every time i save.
Why does that happens do u know?

Comment: The character "\" is used for escaping literals. It means that when HTML is rendered, the character next to it will be used as a normal character instead of a special one. It should leave only one "\" when you save it. It's normal and it shouldn't be necessary adding the missing one again everytime you save. If, for some reasons, it isn't working without  you adding it again, that's a bug of Wordpress or whatever framework you are using.

Comment: i am using prestashop.
when i put (/\\d+\\./, "") and save and then come back to the page it's changed to (/\d+\./, "") which is the one working. but if i save again and come back it's changed to (/d+./, ""). Thank you again so so much for the help i will try to implement this also in the product's characteristics where the feature value is also visible with the prefix

Comment: can u edit your answer so it is showing in the top for anyone else trying to hide a prefix like
$(".layered_nocolor").html(function(i, oldhtml){return oldhtml.replace(/\d+\./, "");});  or (/\\d+\\./, "") if the first doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Javascript to split up the text into separate spans, so it can hide the span containing the number prefix.

```js
$(".layered_nocolor").html(function(i, oldhtml) {
  return oldhtml.trim().replace(/^\d+\./, '<span class="hide">$&</span>');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label class="layered_nocolor">
      1.alpha
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="layered_nocolor">
      2.beta
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="layered_nocolor">
      30.gama
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sry guys this didn't work maybe because i didn't mention that the text in the html is in quotes "1.alpha" but in the site they are not visible. ididn't mention them cause i thought tha the code u could provide me was just a find the prefix and hide it sry for being unclear.
this is my site it's in greek. http://aurorahome.gr/13-sentonia could u take a look on the actual html of the filter "Διάσταση" and not the crappy example i gave you. so sorry guys

Comment: The basic idea is still the same. Just adjust the regular expression to match your actual code.

Comment: I'm sorry for you. But it's not our problem that you're trying to create a website without the necessary education.

Comment: i know but i still have to try and learn by doing it. Actually it's done except some minor details or some huge i missed completely due to my ignorance

Comment: Go to regular-expression.info, it has a tutorial on regular expressions.